# Get unmarked data from db

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql

WHAT I'M DOING:

I'm writing a C# application which will help employees process emails. I have a database with mails (SQL Server 2008 Express). One table contains the mails themselves (each row has columns like `msgId, sender, recipients, subject, body` etc) and the other table contains data of how the mails have been processed by employees - whenever an email has some property assigned, a new row with the property is saved to the second table.

The second table contains columns: `msgId, forTeam, notForTeam, processedByTeam`. Whenever an employee marks a message as related to his team, a row is saved with `TEAMXX` value in the `forTeam` column. Whenever an employee performs other actions on the email, a row with `TEAMXX` value is saved in the `processedByTeam` column.

I'm trying to get emails to display in the "Unprocessed" view, ie. mails which have following values:

```
forTeam: null
notForTeam: everything different than 'TEAM01'
processedByTeam: everything different than 'TEAM01'
```

I've been trying to write many different queries but it still doesn't work the way I want and it's driving me nuts. Will be grateful for the correct query.

EXAMPLE:

Table with mails (`Mails`):

```
msgId sender  subject body  received (sortingTime)
53    x@x.com test    test  2012-05-11 11:00
54    b@b.com test2   test2 2012-05-10 10:00
55    h@h.com blah    blah  2012-05-11 12:00
56    t@t.com dfgg    dfgg  2012-05-11 12:30
```

Table with assignments (`MailAssignments`):

```
msgId forTeam notForTeam  processedByTeam
54    null    TEAM02      null            - this means TEAM02 hid the mail from their view
54    TEAM01  null        null            - this means TEAM01 assigned the mail to them
54    null    null        TEAM01          - TEAM01 has processed the mail

53    TEAM01  null        null            - invisible to other teams
53    null    TEAM01      null            - invisible for TEAM01 (and also for others because of the above)

56    TEAM01  null        null
56    null    null        TEAM01          - mail processed by TEAM01
```

Now, I want my C# app to have a view which will display mails as "Unprocessed", ie.:

1. mail 54 was first hidden for TEAM02 - should be invisible for them
2. mail 54 was assigned to TEAM01 - should be now visible for them in "This Team's" view
3. mail 54 was processed by TEAM01 - should be now invisible in "This Team's" view
4. mail 53 was assigned to TEAM01 - should visible in their "This Team's" view (and ONLY for them)
5. mail 53 was hidden for TEAM01 - should be invisible to TEAM01 (and for anyone else because of prev. action)
6. mail 56 was assigned to TEAM01 - should be now visible only to TEAM01 in "This Team's"
7. mail 56 was processed by TEAM01 - should be now invisible for TEAM01 in "This Team's"

So, with the present data in both tables, finally, TEAM01 should see in their "Unprocessed" view only:

```
mail 55
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @teamName varchar(50) = 'TEAM01'

SELECT * 
FROM Mails M
LEFT OUTER JOIN MailAssignments MA ON M.msgId = MA.msgId
WHERE MA.msgId IS NULL OR 
      (
         MA.forTeam IS NULL AND 
         MA.notForTeam <> @teamName AND 
         MA.processedByTeam <> @teamName
      )
```

Would this do what you want?

Comment: ok, I will have to test it longer but for now seems to work perfectly!